# How can I write this function in MatLab? I got a Matrix Error

Tags: matlab

How can I write this function in MatLab? I got a Matrix Error when typing the following in:

```
n=1:100; k=0.5; x(n)=sin((3*pi*n)/20); y(n)=x(n/k);scale (x,k)
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about _Mathematica_ programming

Comment: First, you need to write `x=sin((3*pi*n)/20)` and not `x(n)=sin((3*pi*n)/20)`, second, you can't write x(n/k), and What happens when n>50 and k=0.5? the result is > 100 which is outside the length of x. are you trying to do  x(n(1:2:end)) may be?

Comment: Somehow I feel he thinks that x is a variable and therefor x(n/k) is supposed to be the result he would be getting when calculating y=sin((3*pi*n/k)/20). But I might also be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You are evaluating the functions to a vector, further processing these data points is sometimes very tricky. Try function handles instead:

```
x=@(n)sin((3.*pi.*n)./20)

y=@(n)x(n./k)
```

Please note, that I replaced the matrix multiplication with element-wise operations, which allows processing of vectors.

To evaluate a function handle to a vector, use `y(n)` or `x(n)`